# Find kernel of homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}_2, f(a+bi) = a+b$. How can I show that kernel of this homomorphism is $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

What I've tried:
$ker(f) = f^{-1}(\{0\})$. $a+b = 0 \implies a = b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So $a$ and $b$ needs to have the same parity in $\mathbb{Z}$. But how can I continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very good start! In fact, this is biconditional: $f(a+bi) = 0$ if and only if $a = b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Now we fully understand $\ker(f)$!

Next, we need to fully understand $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$. An arbitrary element of $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$ looks like

$$(1+i)(x+iy) = (x-y) + i(x+y).$$

Now to show that these two sets are the same, you need to show that they have the same elements. Can you see why any element of $\ker(f)$ will also be an element of $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and that any element of $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$ will also have to be an element of $\ker(f)$?

Comment: +1, very nice answer! (Alternatively, one may note that $2 = (1+i)(1-i)$, which shows that  $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$ contains every element $x+yi$ of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $x$ and $y$ have equal parity. Then it just remains to show that $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$ belongs to the kernel, as at the end of your solution.)

Comment: Ok. Now to show that $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$ belongs to kernel: Let $x \in (1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i] \implies x = (1+i)(a+bi)$, so $f(x) = f((1+i)(a+bi)) = f(1+i)f(a+bi)$, but $f(1+i)=1+1=0$, so $f(x) = 0$, so $x \in ker(f)$. Is ok?

Comment: @AlexWertheim ?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk ?

Comment: @MathLearner yep, looks fine to me!

Comment: But I still have a question. What's the intuition behind. Why we looked on $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$ ? I understand that it's ok. But why we choose this?

Comment: Well, if you're willing to accept a few facts about $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, you can reverse engineer things a bit. The kernel of any ring homomorphism is an ideal of the domain, so we're looking for an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. In this case, our ring homomorphism is a surjection onto a field, so the kernel must a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Now, recall that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, so all ideals are generated by some element, and maximal ideals are generated by irreducible elements. I think $1+i$ is one of the more natural elements to notice is in the kernel, so we have to conclude that the...

Comment: ...kernel contains $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$. But $1+i$ is irreducible (it has norm $2$), and so the ideal $(1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is maximal, hence exactly the kernel.